# Magento cart count not update

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, mini-cart

When I purchase any product cart count not update when I refresh that page at that time cart count update. I want to need without refresh it's been update.

`/app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml`

```
<div class="form-group">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>" class="cart-link <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
    <!--<span class="cartbtn"><img src="<?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/minicart.png'); ?>" alt="Cart"></span>--->
    <div class="Shopping_Cart">
     <div class="cart_ttl"><span><?php echo $this->__('') ?></span></div>
    <span class="count">(<?php echo $_cartQty; ?>)-</span>
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__(''); ?></span>
    <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getQuote()->getSubtotal()) ?></span>
    <!---<span class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-minicart"></span>  -->
</a>
</div>
  <div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_content');?>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your ajax addtocart code in question

Comment: <div class="cntnt">

                   <span style="color:red;"> <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></span>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>

                    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">

                        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

                        <table class="table table-hover clearfix cart-table data-table form-group" id="shopping-cart-table">

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: You have posted page code not ajax code and add code in question not in comment

Comment: If you are facing this issue with default magento code and not your own Add to cart related customization then you should follow this issue about it that is reported here - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5946 . If you are facing this issue with your own add to cart customization/AJAX call, then post your code in your question

Comment: Still my mini cart count not working

Comment: Any one help me on this